# Drupal8 Configuration directories error

Tags: drupal-8

I've installed Drupal8 locally using Acquia Dev Desktop interface. 
I've got error as below in Reports/Status Report:

Configuration directories   Not present
Your sites/drupal-8-2-6.dd/settings.php file must define the $config_directories variable as an array containing the names of directories in which configuration files can be found. It must contain a sync key.

I also could not push to Cloud Dev(internet interface) because it shows  error as below:

Requirement Problem:
Configuration directories   Not present
Your /settings.php file must define the $config_directories variable as an array containing the names of directories in which configuration files can be found. It must contain a sync key.

My setting.php is under ~/Documents/DRUPAL/drupal-8.2.6/sites/default/settings.php

Should I make changings in this file?
What changes need to make to get rid from error?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Precise detailed steps for the user6781412 solution at:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2891394

===

@user6781412 : Thanks

I detailed your solution in precise detail for newbies like myself, but this bloody forum keeps regecting it on the grounds that "Your post appears to contain code, blah, blah, blah."

I gave up after about an additional half-hour trying to format my solution for this site, and have instead posted it at the above URL at drupal.org.

You da' one. Peace out.

"All the best; intended."

Christopher James Francis Rodgers

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem and fixed error by creating sync dir. outside  of my root. So in this case I've created sync.dir under  ~/Documents/DRUPAL and left it empty. 
Then I've created code that pointing to this dir as below:

```
$config_directories = array(

// REPLACE THIS PATH for your path

CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY => '~/Documents/DRUPAL/drupal_sync',

);
```

This fixed error.

Short history of sync directory:

"Sync directory contains configuration files that help move your site from your local development machines to the production servers. In the past, all configuration was contained in the database and moving from development to production was very troublesome".